# Factor `country` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na`

Tags: r, dplyr, data-analysis, tidyr, forcats

i have been trying to analyse a certain piece of code using tidyr and this is the error that keeps popping i am quite new to this and i am stuck , can anyone tell me whats wrong with this piece of code

## error thrown is

**Error: object 'confirmed' not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Factor `country` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na`
2: Factor `type` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na`**

and i have tried using `forcats::fct_explicit_na` on both the variables but it doesnt seem to work
any and all help would be very appreciated

## reprex is

```r
data %>%
  filter(date == max(date)) %>%
  select(country = Country.Region, type, cases) %>%
  group_by(country, type) %>%
  summarise(total_cases = sum(cases)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = type,
              values_from = total_cases) %>%
  arrange(-confirmed)
#> Error in data %>% filter(date == max(date)) %>% select(country = Country.Region, : could not find function "%>%"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Can you `dput()` your data to make this a [reprex]. Also, the error in the code block is not the error you are describing. Try adding `library("tidyverse")` at the start of your code when producing the reprex. (+1 for using the reprex package).

Comment: You probably want `arrange(desc(confirmed))` in your last line.

Comment: thanks for the response ,  i did use (tidyverse) earlier, anyways the problem is fixed now by reinstalling the app and using the same piece of code  .thanks for the help though . much appreciated